# Why is my Vimspector debugging session not initializing?

Tags: python, debugging, vim

I configured my `vimspector.json`file and want to launch the debugger but when I do that it just says that it is initializing the debugger:
[image]

this is is my `Vimspector.json`:

```
{
    "configurations": {
    "test":{
                "adapter": "vscode-python",
                "configuration": {
                                "name": "this is a python test",
                                "type": "python",
                                "request": "launch",
                                "program":
"~/Documents/coding/python/terminal_game1/Terminal-Game/terminal_game.py"
                            }
            }
}
}
```

Does anybody know what this means and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Update:
After I've tried to use the `debugpy`-adapter the problem doesn't occur anymore and the debugger initializes correctly. But when trying to use the `vscode-python` adapter it still doesn't work even though I have installed its adapter via `:VimspectorInstall vscode-python` which ran successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The adapter "vscode-python" is now declared legacy (No longer supported, please migrate your config), the supported adapter for python is now "debugpy".

so just replace `vscode-python` with `debugpy` in your `.vimspector.json`

This can be found on the plugin's Github page [here](https://github.com/puremourning/vimspector#supported-languages).